Facebook login API blocked even with approved appeal
I used facebook login API on my website but suddenly it got blocked because I didnt had a facebook test user to let them test my api in some yearly inspections.
I provided all the information on the appeal and It got approved but my API is still blocked and I can't appeal anymore. Can it be a bug? I have to do something else?
In my API panel I have this error:

When I enter on the link I got redirected to https://developers.facebook.com/appeal/ instead of the appeal link, and It's says there is nothing to appeal:

Also I  tried to write in the community forums but it's says "You have to be registeded to post" but ofc I'm, i wouldnt be able to have a facebook API if not...

